# Terminator on Windows subsystem on Linux needs two enters to work!

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, terminator

When I start terminator on Windows subsystem on Linux I need to write the command and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice to run a command **only for the first time**, then it becomes normal, some info:

on PowerShell:

```
$wsl --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2
Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 8/24/2022
WSL automatic updates are on.
Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
```

on WSL:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I'm also using AutoHotkey to launch the terminal, but I don't think it has to do anything with this problem.  Any thoughts? :-/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  A few questions - Are you using WSLg or some other X server?   Are you on Windows 11?

Comment: Thx, yes I'm on windows 11, but i don't really know if am using wslg or x server

Comment: Ok, try `wsl --version`.  If it just gives help text, then that's useful information as well.  But if it reports version information, please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1449859/edit) it into the question.  Also, what's your `echo $DISPLAY` show?  Thanks!

Comment: `wsl --version`
WSL version: 1.0.3.0                                                                                                    Kernel version: 5.15.79.1                                                                                               WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.1105
sorry for the formatting.

Comment: And echo $DISPLAY gives `:0`
I tried `wsl --update`, and i think that made the trick. Now it works fine. Thanks for the help.